# How to select rows which have same set of values in two columns and hence concatenate the values in the third column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaYER.png)

I have the sample values as shown in the image attached.
What I want to achieve is that the value of PR_NUMBER field gets concatenated on the basis of same values in PO_NUMBER and PO_ITEM.

Though this is a sample data, any n number of rows can have the same values and hence the concatenation of all such values in the PR_NUMBER column need to be done.

I got to know about CURSORS to loop through the table but don't really know what to do with them.

Expected output image is

```
123 | 1 | 5678,6789
456 | 1 | 2322,3432
456 | 2 | 4678
```

Comment: which db you are really using  .. ?????

Comment: don't use loops in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SAP HANA then  you can use STRING_AGG(Name, ',')

```
 SELECT po_number, po_item, STRING_AGG(pr_number, ',')
 from your_table
 group by po_number, po_item;
```

instead if you are using mysql you can use group_concat

```
 SELECT po_number, po_item, group_concat(pr_number, ',')
 from your_table
 group by po_number, po_item;
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out already that STRING_AGG is the substitute to GROUP_CONTACT.
By the way, is there any way  to do it without the function?

Comment: whit sql  not  .. if you don't want use  a db brand  related  function  you must performe the aggregation  using a procedural approach on a full select ..

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select po_number, po_item, group_concat(pr_number)
from t
group by po_number, po_item;
```

Comment: It says that GROUP_CONCAT is not a supported function. :/